# Playing sequence of PNG files in cocos2d iphone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I want to play an sequence of png files for animation.
I tried executing the following code in cocos2d iphone

```
(void) onEnter {

    [super onEnter];    

    roadSprite=[[Sprite spriteWithFile:@"R00.png"] retain];
    [roadSprite setPosition:ccp(240,160)];
    [self addChild:roadSprite z:5];

    Animation* animation = [Animation animationWithName:@"animation" delay:0];
    for( int i=0;i<25;i++)
    {

        [animation addFrameWithFilename: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"R%02d.png", i]];

    }

    id action1 = [Animate actionWithAnimation: animation];

    [roadSprite runAction:action1];

}
```

The animation doesnt get played instead the R00.png gets displayed lastly.
Can anyone help me to find the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see much of anything going wrong there, except perhaps in the setting of the delay.

You're setting delay to 0. Delay doesn't mean "how long should I wait before playing this animation" but it means "how much time must I wait before displaying each picture". Setting that to 0 would mean it doesn't wait at all, and your animation is finished! Tada!

Set your delay to the amount of time between each frame. In normal animation, this is 1.0f/24.0f (or 0.04, rounded off)